# getting the href value from anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have a link

```
<ul class="sub_menu">
    <li><a href="caps">Caps</a></li>
    <li><a href="jeans">Jeans</a></li>
    <li><a href="shorts">Shorts</a></li>
    <li><a href="foootwear">Footwear</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to grab the `href` value, I tried the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.sub_menu a').click(function() {
        var txt = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(txt);
    )};
)};
```

but I get this error

```
 The requested URL /new/caps was not found on this server.
```

I don't want to grab the text, I have succeeded with that using `.text();`, I want the `href` value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `return false` to the end of your `click` event handler to stop the execution of the link.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.sub_menu a').click(function() {
        var txt = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(txt);
        return false;
    )};
)};
```

You can also use `event.preventDefault()` if you want the event to still propagate up the DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.sub_menu a').click(function(event) {
        var txt = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(txt);
        event.preventDefault();
    )};
)};
```

Note: In a jQuery event handler, `return false;` is the same as calling `event.preventDefault().stopPropagation();`.

Comment: +1 for pointing out why you might want to use preventDefault instead and the quickest answer! Cheers

Comment: @jasper ur code worked for me i further passed it via $.ajax and retrieved some data using that href value but the link in address bar is new/# i want it new/caps

Comment: Are you aware that if you change the URL in the address bar that you will change the page to the new URL? The only piece of information you can change in the address bar without forwarding the user to a new page is the hash (everything past the `#` symbol). I'm not sure what you want to be your end result but if you just want to save the state of the page then save it in the hash of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.sub_menu a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var txt = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(txt);
    )}; 
)};
```

Notice: `e.preventDefault();` This prevent's the default link behavior (navigating to) when you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul.sub_menu a').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).attr('href');
   alert(txt);
   return false;
)};
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two problems:

1. you need to use `event.preventDefault();` or `return false` to stop the click **AND**
2. you need to fix the `)` in your code.  Right now they are out of place.  In both instances you have `)};`.  Should be `});`

Code should be

```
$('ul.sub_menu li a').click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var txt = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(txt);    
}); <-- here is where the parantheses are wrong.
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Lz2Sw/